# How to create a scoring algorithm based on the interactions of two trends?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, algorithms

I have two variables represented as a time-series with monthly observations. I am attempting to create a scoring system -1 to 1 where: 1 represents a strong shift in trend from B to A and -1 represents a strong shift in trend from A to B. Ultimately, I am looking to score the magnitude of trend change / momentum from A to B (vice-versa).

For example, given the sample data points in Example 1 below, the trend in A drops instantly and the trend in B increases. So the score should be close to -1.

```
Example 1

A = {20, 0, 0, 0, 0}
B = {0, 20, 15, 18, 30}
```

Conversely, the sample data points in Example 2 below illustrates the trend in B dropping instantly and the trend in A increases. So the score should be close to 1.

```
Example 2

A = {0, 5, 10, 12, 8}
B = {5, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Lastly, the sample data points in Example 3 below is mixed and the score would be negative but not as negative as in Example 1.

```
Example 3

A = {5, 8, 7, 4, 3}
B = {0, 0, 2, 5, 10}
```

I tried perhaps utilizing correlation or Granger causality, but did not quite address the requirements. Tried to search around but could not quite hone down to a feasible solution. Is there a general formula for scoring the trend changes between A and B?

Comment: The scoring-rules tag does not fit here

Comment: @picky_porpoise Thank you. Removed the tag accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there's a widely used measure for this, but I would come up with an ad-hoc solution. One example could be subtracting trend B from trend A. Therefore, this new trend of the difference would be somewhat similar to what you expect: negative when B is larger than A; positive when A is larger than B. You just need to place a normalization factor, which could be the sum of the values of trend A and B at that point.

I am assuming (from your examples) that both trends are discrete and positive. Let's call this metric D. See below:

$$ D_{i} = \frac{a_{i}-b_{i}}{a_{i}+b_{i}} $$

where the i-th value of this metric ($D_{i}$) is the difference between the i-th value of trend A ($a_{i}$) minus the i-th value of trend B ($b_{i}$), divided by a normalization factor which is the sum of both. This follows what you expect:

- If both $a,b=0$ or if $a=b$, the metric value is zero.
- If $a=0$, then the value is -1.
- If $b=0$, then the value is +1.
- In any intermediate case, you would lie in a range between -1 and +1.

As said, this is quite ad-hoc, and maybe there's some metric from the field of time series (with which I am not familiar at all) and someone else can better help you. But this does exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for this! This seems to be pointing to the right direction. Given that the scoring formula is for each i-th value, if I wanted an overall score - would it be feasible to take the average of D?

Comment: From what you described, I thought you wanted to do this for each pair of values. But of course, an average of a range of values could be a reasonable thing to do. It depends on what data you are working with and what you want to do with it. I think you should be the one making that choice, and making an argument about it.

Comment: I see - thanks again. In the event we would like to account for the magnitude, is there a separate metric that could do this ad-hoc? For example, 20 to 0 would be less in magnitude than 50 to 0.

Comment: Then, if I got your question correctly, I'd say simply remove the normalization factor in the denominator. You could come up with other metrics, but I think this one is the simplest and most informative one to give information about the magnitude of the difference. An example of an alternative is to use in the denominator the average of the historical differences between data points from the two sets. In that case, you provide a measure of the magnitude (when >1, difference is above average).